# Best practice to construct an Instance

Tags: c++, initialization

In C++, I notice that initialization is a complicated topic for me. I came across maybe five different ways to construct an instance, and that's got me confused. When do I have to use one way over another way?

```
class A
{
private:
    int x;
    float y;
    
public:
    A(int xa, float ya) { x = xa; y = ya; };
};

int main()
{
    A a = A(1, 2);
    
    A b = {1, 2};
    
    A c(1, 2);
    
    A d = A{1, 2};

    A e{1, 2};
}
```

Comment: Obligatory [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis.  An hour long presentation on the initialization syntax pain point in C++.

Comment: Well, I think you can certainly exclude that stuff which doesn't compile: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0377809b41d2b97

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, what are you say for just a stupid semicolon is messed up

Comment: @AccessDenied I fixed that, look closer please. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ada493d29f3c094e

Comment: @AccessDenied you missed an example: `A e{1, 2};`

Comment: It is not that simple as "what is the best". Those two approaches `{}` and `()` have different behavior. For example in case of defaulted default constructor inside the template function; and yes, initializer list. Thus, sometimes you must use `{}`, sometimes `()`, sometimes both work and you can choose any. That is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Eljay said, [Nicolai Josuttis covers this thoroughly in "The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs).

Usually curly braces initialization does the right thing. It prevents [the most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) and narrowing conversions.

For your example, this would be

```
A c{1,2.0};
```

The main problem that comes to mind is when it's ambiguous if you wanted the initializer list constructor or the n-argument constructor:

```
std::vector<std::size_t> x{100, 30};
std::vector<std::size_t> y(100, 30);
```

What is `x.size()`? `y.size()`? I believe `x.size()==2` and `y.size()==100`.

In this situation, personally, I would write a helper function to construct the vector of n copies of the same element so I don't have to think about the subtle difference between these:

```
temmplate<class T>
auto vector_of_n_copies(std::size_t n, T) {
  auto const v = std::vector<T>(n,T);
  assert(v.size()==n);
  return v;
}
```

Additionally, you should initialize in the constructor via member initialization like this:

```
class A{
  int x;
  float y;
 public:
  A(int xa, float ya): x{xa}, y{ya} {}
};
```

From [C++ Core Guidelines, C.49: Prefer initialization to assignment in constructors](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-initialize),

> **Reason** An initialization explicitly states that initialization, rather than assignment, is done and can be more elegant and efficient. Prevents “use before set” errors.